# Avoiding dependency check on Application Launch

Tags: android, google-play

> Is it possible to avoid dependency check on the Startup of Application
>   ?

In my specific case it is about **Google Play Services**. My App would like to use it, but not until users decides to play the game. Otherwise the App is just a regular (non-gaming app).

And I would not want to force my users to install Google Play Services, when they do not intend to use the App for the Game and on the other hand, I would like to avoid creating two seperate Apps, because the Game is connected to the theme of the Main Application I have.

Thanks,
David